# Ext JS Combo box with a text box

Tags: jquery, json, extjs, combobox

I'm new to Ext JS and I wanted to know if there is a way I could do something like this? (I understand, I can have the Combo box as editable instead of this. But wanted to know if I can do this.)

[image: Combo-box with Text-box]

Comment: Do you want the entered item to be added to the list of preexisting items so that next time you visit this combo, the value is available for selection?

Comment: No. I just need the Name of the selected item, and it need not be added to the existing items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but you have to extend ComboBox. One of the things you need to change is `tpl`.

If you have never done something like that, you can look at Saki's LovCombo.

Comment: That looks great.. Will give it a shot with Textbox and will let you know. Thanks a lot @Francesco.

Comment: This is really only a fraction of the work you'll have to do. The rendering of the input field is the easiest part IMHO. Next you will have to hook up the input field with code that will read the value, add it to the store (optionally syncing the store with the server), set the value in the ComboBox and close the list. Not rocket science but it will surely require a bit of in-depth know how of Ext's ComboBox. However, if you are only responsible for the ui design, then you are well off ;)

Comment: @mistaecko.. You are right! I've been using Ext JS for a week and I haven't tried anything with templates before (So, didn't see this coming). Now I'm stuck in a place where the text box is just another Combobox item (Which is un-editable). Will highly appreciate if you could direct me somewhere from here.

Comment: As I said, `tpl` is *one* of the things to change. Template is just DOM rendering, you have to accept the value typed. To do that, you have several choice. Maybe you could register an "enter key pressed" event and do a combo.setValue(stringTypedInInput) which surely works in Ext3. If you type in the input and then click somewhere outside the combo, would you like to save the value (in that case there is beforecollapse) or discard it? Really, start reading LovCombo source ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var strCmbDip = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 storeId: 'strCmbDip',
 fields: ['id','name'],
 proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'rtvstore.php',
    reader: {
        root: 'rootCmbDip'
    }     
 }
});    

var cmbDip = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',
    x: 150,
    width: 230,
    id: 'cmbDip',
    fieldLabel: 'Dip',
    labelAlign: 'top',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    emptyText: 'Select....',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    editable: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    minChars: 1,
    hideTrigger: true,
    loadingText: '',
    store: strCmbDip
});
```

Comment: Isn't this a regular Combo box?

Comment: Read the question, jack! If this is not a candidate for a downvote I don't know. Oh well, he doesn't have any reputation yet.

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney.. Marked that as "Not an answer". But thanks for the effort anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the *tpl* in Ext Designer and it worked. Though the answer is what @Francesco said, I'm just adding the XTemplate I used for reference.

```
<tpl for="."><li>{Name}</li></tpl><input type="text" value="Enter item"></input>
```